# Swift ObjectMapper: Force mapping of JSON number to String

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

This has me stumped.. I'm using Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper currently and am wondering how I can map a JSON object, with a *number* element, to a *string* element.  The JSON object I get from an API call looks like this and is stored in a String variable *orderJson*:

```
{
    "PickOrder": {
        "OrderType": "SalesOrder",
        "OrderNumber": 50058,
        "OrderID": 52,
        "Customer": "Rusty Bike Shop"
    }
}
```

I've setup the following class mappable class:

```
class Order: Mappable {
    var OrderType:   String = ""
    var OrderNumber: String = ""
    var OrderID:     UInt = 0
    var Customer:    String = ""

    required init(_ map: Map) { }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        OrderType <- map["OrderType"]
        OrderNumber <- map["OrderNumber"]
        OrderID <- map["OrderID"]
        Customer <- map["Customer"]
    }
}
```

At runtime, when the Order class is decoded from the JSON, each element of the class is decoded and assigned correctly; however, the **OrderNumber** isn't mapped and is still an empty string.

I'm decoding the JSON string with the following call:

```
let order = Mapper<Order>().map(String(orderJson))
```

How can I force the mapper to convert the element to a string even though it is a number in the JSON object?  The reason I ask is that the API I'm working with will sometimes send  **OrderNumber** as a string and sometimes as a plain number.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Agreed, it may be overkill for this simple example, however, I have many many objects that need to be mapped and most of them are complex with multiple nested objects and arrays of objects.  @vadian Do you know how I can solve the question I posed?

Comment: Map the object "manually" in this case.